# Ubuntu Installing Nginx Behind Proxy Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

**I would like to install Nginx with Phusion Passenger support**

I have:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  
ruby-1.9.3-p194  
Rails 3.2.7  
I am behind the proxy(http://10.10.16.8:3128) 

test@U205-UBUNTU:~$ printenv | grep htt  
http_proxy=http://10.10.16.8:3128  
https_proxy=https://10.10.16.8:3128
```

When I run **rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module** I get an timeout error:

```
  PCRE (required by Nginx) not installed, downloading it...  
    # wget -O /tmp/root-passenger-5079/pcre.tar.gz http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pcre/pcre/8.30/pcre-8.30.tar.gz  
    --2012-07-30 13:12:27--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pcre/pcre/8.30/pcre-8.30.tar.gz  
    Resolving downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.59  
    Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.59|:80... failed:
    Connection timed out.  
    Retrying.
```

It looks like there is no access through proxy.

But when I try to run `wget -O /tmp/root-passenger-5079/pcre.tar.gz http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pcre/pcre/8.30/pcre-8.30.tar.gz` separately everything works fine.

Could Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution.
Problem was that sudo cut the env variables.
To persist the env variables such as http_proxy, ftp_proxy you have to add to /etc/sudoers file this line:

```
Defaults env_keep="no_proxy http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy XAUTHORIZATION \
XAUTHORITY TZ PS2 PS1 PATH MAIL LS_COLORS KRB5CCNAME HOSTNAME HOME DISPLAY COLORS"
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

`sudo vim /etc/wgetrc`

and edit these lines:

```
https_proxy = http://<proxyaddress>:<port>/
http_proxy = http://<proxyaddress>:<port>/
ftp_proxy = http://<proxyaddress>:<port>/
```

(replace `<proxyaddress>` and `<port>` with you settings)